# templateUrl not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was just testing basic angular code, and I had everything working with only **template**, but not with **templateUrl**. I don't include previous code because everything else was working EXECEPT for when I changed to templateUrl and moved everything in my previous template to an external HTML. Could this be a problem with accessing addition HTML files?:

In my HTML,

```
<header></header>
```

In my JS,

```
...
restrict: 'E',
templateUrl: '/journal/journalcontent.html'
```

In journalcontent.html,

```
<div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a plnkr or jsfiddle. It's 99% an issue with your path. Try out `templateUrl: 'journal/journalcontent.html'`

Answer (score 0):

Check the **network tab from developer tools**.
What AngularJS does is to take "/journal/journalcontent.html" and tries to check in the $templateCache helper - if it doesn't find it loaded there already, it will try to download it based on current URL - and this should be visible with a 404 or 200 in your network tab.

If your user responsiveness is really important and it's a reusable template, you could consider to define it in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/journal/journalcontent.html">
    <div>my stuff</div>
</script>
```

Comment: And what if it doesn't find it in the templateCache? When I switched to templateUrl, all the content in my div just didn't display